# Ihave difficulties to recover my variable id in the inspector

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, inspector

can you please help me to get the value of id in the inspector on unity.
i have a json in the unity console, i did a program to access the data in this json and then recovering it in the unity inspector. For the "position" it is worked but for "id" no. i have tried many methods but it didn't worked.

This is my code in start function and in the update function, i have searched but i didn't found how to do it for id:

I'm using SimpleJSON.

```
if(mono != null)
{
     JSONNode id = Face["mono"]["id"].AsInt; 
     JSONNode position = Face["mono"]["position"];
     Vector3 pos = new Vector3(position["x"].AsFloat, position["y"].AsFloat, position["z"].AsFloat);
     int ident = new ident(id);
    
     x = pos.x;
     y = pos.y;
     z = pos.z;
     id= ident.id;
}

private void Update()
{
     Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(x, y, z);
     gameObject.transform.localPosition = newPosition;
}
```

And this is my json:
{
"cmd": "data",
"frame_time": "2021-06-10T11:16:54.678596+00:00",
"start_time": "2021-06-10T10:35:40.516632+00:00",
"streams": [
{
"name": "usb0.1245.2",
"objects": [
{
"name": "face",
"mono": {
"id": "18",
"position": {
"x": "0.073997",
"y": "-0.024979",
"z": "0.677220"
}
},
"multi": [
{
"id": "18",
"position": {
"x": "0.073997",
"y": "-0.024979",
"z": "0.677220"
}
}
]
}
]
}
],
"play": {"list": "test",
"item": "right_key"
}
}

Comment: not familiar with SimpleJson, so sorry if the comment is misleading but in line `JSONNode id = Face["mono"]["id"].AsInt;`, doest  `Face["mono"]["id"].AsInt;` return an `int` instead of a `JSONNode`? If so, the `id` would be there already with no need of `int ident = new ident(id);`

Comment: thank you for your response, yes Face["mono"]["id"].AsInt returns an int but i didn't get it in the inspector because i have to make the id in the update function, i tried to make var id = new var (id); but i didn't worked

Comment: not sure what you mean by get in the inspector. I think you mean the unity inspector. Posted some code in an answer in case it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get an `int` from `Face["mono"]["id"].AsInt;` you can set it in the inspector by setting a `public` or a `[SerializeField] private` variable of your class like this:

```
public myInt = 0; //also [SerializeField] private myInt = 0;
if(mono != null)
{
     myInt = Face["mono"]["id"].AsInt; 
     JSONNode position = Face["mono"]["position"];
     Vector3 pos = new Vector3(position["x"].AsFloat, position["y"].AsFloat, position["z"].AsFloat);
     int ident = new ident(id);
    
     x = pos.x;
     y = pos.y;
     z = pos.z;
     id= ident.id;
}

private void Update()
{
     Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(x, y, z);
     gameObject.transform.localPosition = newPosition;
}
```

Comment: Glad that worked. You can upvote and accept the answer if it did. Happy coding :)